# Problems with secondary live tile in windows 8

Tags: windows-8

i have a problem with a secondary live tile. I pin it within my application and i want
that it get the user to a deep link, where he pinned it.
In the App.xaml.cs file i add this to the onlaunched event:

```
if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // Wenn der Navigationsstapel nicht wiederhergestellt wird, zur ersten Seite navigieren
            // und die neue Seite konfigurieren, indem die erforderlichen Informationen als Navigationsparameter
            // übergeben werden

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Arguments))
            {
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(qurandb));//, args.Arguments);
            }
            else
            {
                //  rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(qurandb), args.Arguments);
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(GroupedItemsPage), "AllGroups");
            }

        /*    if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(GroupedItemsPage), "AllGroups"))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            } */
        }
```

My problem is, that this is only working when the app is launched for the first time. When i click later on the secondary tile (the app is resume), i dont get to the destination i want, but to the point, where i was when i suspended the app.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app's OnLaunched event will be called when the secondary tile is clicked upon.  The code you provided assumes that it will only be called when `rootFrame.Content` is null, and is not navigating to the appropriate page if your app is already running.  The code needs to handle the case where the frame content is not null.

```
if (rootFrame.Content == null)
{
    ...
} else {
    // Need to handle the case where rootFrame.Content is not null
}
```

Comment: thank you. The code i have provided is in the OnLaunched event..Do i get it right, that i need to add code to the OnActivated event, as this is fired, when i click on the secondary tile?

Comment: The OnLaunched event will be fired - launch is a specific kind of activation.  I've updated my response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the OnResuming event as follows:

In your App.xaml.cs

```
public App() 
{
    //...
    this.Resuming += OnResuming; 
    //...
}

//...

private void OnResuming(object sender, object e) 
{
    //there are no args here to access. So need to figure out some way to decide what page to show
    bool showShowQuranDb = true; //your logic here
    if (shouldShowQuranDb)
    {
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(qurandb));
    }
    else
    {
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(GroupedItemsPage), "AllGroups");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much so far...But what logic could i use, when i cant acess the args of the tile?

Comment: Well, you could use whatever logic you need - because your app is in fact in memory when it is suspended. Which means that when you get the OnResuming event, all your in-memory state is preserved. Also, on suspension, you could save some state either in-memory or to a local file and read it back in on resume.